# Is there a way to prevent the user's click in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to emulate a terminal in html/css/javascript in a Vuejs app. For that I am using a textarea.

The user is not supposed to click on a previous line and update or delete the text. So is it possible to prevent user click in the textarea and only allow keyboard actions ?

Comment: the text area might not be the right kind of element you want.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Just to post my thoughts and recommendations - You should allow them to type in one box as an input at a time. They press enter and it gets appended to a div to display. This helps emulate a command line - You can enter input in one line and submit it, then only view it. A textarea is most likely not the most optimal HTML solution

Comment: I did not think about the simple input solution but I am definitely going to try this out ! Thank you @ZacharyBrooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/gNYyGZ)

You can just prevent default onmousedown event on textarea:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').onmousedown = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp) attribute to your `<textarea>` tag, like this:

```
<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is Possible u can disable the textarea and u can set readonly also

**Textarea with disabled**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is textarea with disabled</h1>

<textarea rows="10" cols="50" disabled>
 dsdkiensdsndsjdnjnjdndjsndajndasjdnasjd
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**Textarea with readonly**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is Textarea with readonly</h1>


<textarea rows="10" cols="50" readonly>
 dsdkiensdsndsjdnjnjdndjsndajndasjdnasjd
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the css-only solution:

```
<textarea unselectable="on" id="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

```
*.unselectable {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readonly` attribute in your HTML markup.

**Working Example:**

```html
<textarea readonly>
Here is some sample text.
</textarea>
```